# How to disable folding in application.properties in Eclipse STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

After disabling all folding options in `Window->Preferences`, there is still folding enabled while editing `application.properties` using `Eclipse STS 4.2.1` and `Generic Editor - Spring Properties` tool.

Is there a way to remove this folding?

I mean not to expand all that is folded but to completely disable an option to have folding including vertical bar with pluses and minuses.